# problem with kernel

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, initramfs

In the past I had tried to update the Ubuntu kernel with that found on http://www.kernel.org/. Due to some problems I had to revert the changes as my kernel image didn't boot well. 
Since then I get the below error when I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or when I try to install any app:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: 9: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: /usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd: not found
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me get my kernel right.

Answer (score 0):

The missing file `/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/zz-flash-touch-initrd` is part of the package `initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch`. Therefore install it again

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch
```